# What is "women scrapes." ? explain please

Tags: idioms

He was only twenty-two then but had already been in two or three of what were spoken of in Winesburg as *"women scrapes."*

[Source](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~Hyper/ANDERSON/ch17.html)

Comment: Can you please cite the source of this quote?

Comment: short story called "untold lie" i don't remember the author

Comment: @Alexy - The author – in this case, Sherwood Anderson – is [found easily enough](http://www.google.com/search?ls=en&q=short+story+untold+lie&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Answer (score 4):

Scrape is used here as a noun, where it means a difficult or embarrassing situation, usually caused by your own actions.

A 'woman scrape' is therefore a difficult situation involving a woman.  Further down the text it refers to the character 'getting women into trouble' (a euphemism for getting them pregnant).  So these 'scrapes' are likely to be either getting a women pregnant or being at high risk of doing so.